# Tabulate a text file

Tags: vb.net

I have to tabulate a text file, which contains numbers and strings. Here is an example:

```
&OBST XB=   0.000,  15.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   3.000, SURF_ID='CONCRETE', BNDF_OBST=.TRUE.  /
&OBST XB=  15.000,  15.000,   0.000,  10.000,   0.000,   3.000, SURF_ID='CONCRETE', BNDF_OBST=.TRUE.  /
&OBST XB=   0.000,  15.000,  10.000,  10.000,   0.000,   3.000, SURF_ID='CONCRETE', BNDF_OBST=.TRUE.  /
&OBST XB=   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,  10.000,   0.000,   3.000, SURF_ID='CONCRETE', BNDF_OBST=.TRUE.  /
&OBST XB=   0.000,  15.000,   0.000,  10.000,   0.000,   0.000, SURF_ID='CONCRETE', BNDF_OBST=.TRUE.  /
&OBST XB=   0.000,  15.000,   0.000,  10.000,   3.000,   3.000, SURF_ID='CONCRETE', BNDF_OBST=.TRUE.  /
```

What I have to obtain is a Datagridview in which I have six columns and the rows with the numbers. First of all, I loaded this textfile into a Richtextbox and then I tried to split using spaces and commas as separators but, unfortunately, the number of the space isn't always the same so, with the provided code below, I have some problems of tabulation (for example the first row gets skipped):

```
For Each line In RichTextBox2.Lines
    If Not line.Trim.ToString = "" Then
        Dim item() As String = line.Trim.Split(" "c, ","c)
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(item)
    End If
Next
For i = DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 2 To 0 Step -1
    If IsNumeric(DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells.Item(i).Value) = False Then
        DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next
```

How could I solve?

Comment: IMO, you shouldn't load the content of that file in a RichTextBox, it doesn't make sense, since you need to show these lines as Rows in a DataGridView. Also, you should provide a sample of the desired result, a schema of what data the DGV should present when filled.

Comment: It would help if you provide an example of what the grid should look like, perhaps using a screenshot from Excel, in your question

Comment: I also suspect the sample you have provided is not enough to get a comprehensive answer, as lines in FDS input may have many different parameters and formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this.  It uses TextFieldParser.

```
'from
' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=net-5.0
'
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim path As String = "path to text file here"
    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(path)
        MyReader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {",", "="}
        Dim currentRow As String()
        'Loop through all of the fields in the file. 
        'If any lines are corrupt, report an error and continue parsing. 
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                ' Include code here to handle the row.
                Stop ' look at currentRow
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
                " is invalid.  Skipping")
            End Try
        End While
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    Dim dataFile As String = "c:\some folder\path\somefile.txt"
    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadLines(dataFile)
        Dim values() As String = line.Split(",").Take(6)
        If values.Length = 6 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To values.GetUpperBound(0)
                values(i) = values(i).Trim("&OBST XB=".ToCharArray())
            Next
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(values)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```